# Problems with closing the iphone app

Tags: iphone

On other apps I noticed that when you close the app and load it back up you always see the first loading screen. In my app it's only on that first time. Can you please let me know how to sort this out.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are running on iOS 4, so multitasking is activated :-)

If you want to disable multitasking, add this in the .plist file UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (set the key to YES)

Then when to app reload you will see the splash screen.